# Why is the set of all true first-order statements about non-negative integers in the language with only equality, $+$ and $\times$ undecidable?

Tags: logic, incompleteness

Apparently Tarski and Mostowski proved this, but intuitively I'm not seeing the difference between statements in a language of non-negative integers with equality, addition, and multiplication vs [Presburger Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic), which has only equality and addition.  It would seem to me that multiplication with non-negative integers can be represented as repeated addition, so what is it about multiplication that makes statements undecidable?  Or is it some other subtlety that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplication cannot be represented in Presburger arithmetic as repeated addition. To say that $ab=a+a+\cdots +a$ ($b$ times) would use a "sentence" of variable length, and that is not how a sentence is defined. For a *proof* that it cannot be done, combine the Tarski-Mostowski result with the result that Presburger arithmetic is decidable.

Comment: I see, so the variable length of recursive addition is the problem.  What if the length was bounded by some constant?  Would that not allow a definition of $1a = a$, $2a = a + a$, up to the maximum value of $b$?

Comment: We can certainly define $a\times b$ by repeated addition for any *specific* $b$. We could also add axioms (infinitely many, but that's OK) that would give the full multiplication table for natural numbers. But that would not be enough to prove the basic properties of multiplication. For example, I do not see how adding such axioms would enable us to prove that $\forall x\forall y(x\times y=y\times x)$. For a proof also has fixed finite length.

Comment: Would that not follow from the commutative and associative properties of addition? (Please excuse my ignorance on this subject, I recently discovered Presburger arithmetic was decidable and started exploring.)

Comment: I think I see what your getting at.  It is the commutative property of multiplication itself that we cannot prove (in your example) because $x \times y$ when $y$ is constant is not the same as $y \times x$ where $y$ is constant.  This would require another set of infinite axioms, which being axioms, are simply taken as true, not proven.

Comment: For commutativity, if we add the full multiplication table, then we can prove for any *specific* numerals $a$ and $b$ that $a\times b=b\times a$. However, that is not a proof of $\forall x\forall y(x\times y=y\times x)$. I think you may have in mind what is sometimes called the "$\omega$ (omega) rule." That is not a rule of the first-order predicate calculus.